# Dynamically Draggable, Editable and self resizing TextField

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an android app in Eclipse and I need a textfield that can be placed, dragged, and edited by the user on screen. Now I have this working on an absolute layout, which is fine, and I have editing capabilities but I'm looking for something more along the line of how Skitch by evernote does it. has anyone got any ideas or suggestions on how to get that kind of textfield functionality going.

Thanks in advance.
Will recommend any answer that leads in the right direction.

Comment: If you press+hold it, return false on the edit, and implement an OnDragListener, which tells you the new coordinates to place the textfield.

Comment: I use press and hold to enable edit mode, which pops up a dialog where you can change color, font, and size. I would like it to be done on canvas rather than in a dialog. for some reason I can't get that to work.